# Posso usar $_GET com $_SESSION?

Tags: php

Eu tenho esse código PHP funcionando,

```
<?php
include "../conexao.php";
$codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
$nome_marca = $_POST['nome_marca'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM marca order by nome_marca")or die(mysql_error());
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
?>
<ul>
    <li><a href="prod_index_marca.php?codmarca=<?php echo $res['codigo'];?>"><?php echo $res['nome_marca'];?></a></li>
<?php
}
?>
</ul>
```

e que direciona o `href` para a página de acordo com o código referente a marca selecionada.

E a página de destino esta com esse código PHP

```
<?php
include "../conexao.php";
$codmarca = $_GET['codmarca'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produto WHERE codmarca = '$codmarca'");
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

$codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
$img01 = $_POST['img01'];
$descricao = $_POST['descricao'];
$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
$codcategoria = $_POST['codcategoria'];
$codmarca = $_POST['codmarca'];
$preco = $_POST['preco'];
$pagseguro = $_POST['pagseguro'];
$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
?>
```

que recebe os dados via $_GET.

A minha duvida é se tem como adaptar esses códigos para que funcionem com $_SESSION?

E se tiver, os amigos podem me orientar como converte-los, ou mesmo onde posso buscar informações sobre o assunto.

Desde já fica aqui o meu agradecimento a todos, pela a atenção a minha duvida.

Comment: lembrando que session é apenas entre o mesmo domínio, e hoje não é recomendável guardar muitos dados em session

Comment: sinceramente, faz isso não... adaptar código para ficar errado não é uma boa prática!

Answer (score 0):

Eu presumo que você já conheça como uma sessão funciona.

Então praticamente você vai trocar seus *$_POST* por *$_SESSION* (post nesse caso não vai funcionar, pois só é usado em submit de formularios)

Vale lembrar que para usar sessions, você deve inicializar com a função **session_start();** sempre quando for ler ou escrever uma váriavel na sessão. Dê preferência para usar sempre na primeira linha do código, pois se houver uma saída de texto (ou erro de notice ou warning do PHP) vai causar erro no script

segue a documentação oficial do session_start
Eu presumo que você já conheça como uma sessão funciona.

Então praticamente você vai trocar seus *$_POST* por *$_SESSION* (post nesse caso não vai funcionar, pois só é usado em submit de formularios)

Vale lembrar que para usar sessions, você deve inicializar com a função **session_start();** sempre quando for ler ou escrever uma váriavel na sessão. Dê preferência para usar sempre na primeira linha do código, pois se houver uma saída de texto (ou erro de notice ou warning do PHP) vai causar erro no script

segue a documentação oficial do session_start()
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-start.php